# An art dealer receives five old paintings, given that a painting chosen at random is a forgery what is the probability that all are forgeries?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

An art dealer receives a shipment of five old paintings from abroad, and, on the basis of past experience,
she feels that the probabilities are, respectively, 0.76, 0.09,
0.02, 0.01, 0.02, and 0.10 that 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or all 5 of them
are forgeries. Since the cost of authentication is fairly
high, she decides to select one of the five paintings at random and send it away for authentication. If it turns out
that this painting is a forgery, what probability should she
now assign to the possibility that all the other paintings
are also forgeries?

So far I tried assigning A as the event all paintings are forgeries and N that none of the paintings are forgeries so the required probability becomes P(A|N*) = $$\left(\frac{P(A \cap N*)}{P(N*)}\right)$$

which gives $\left(\frac{0.10}{0.24}\right)$ cause $P( A \cap N*) = $ P (A) = 0.10 and P(N*) = 1-0.76 = 0.24
and my answer is o.4166 but the textbook gives the answer as 0.6757

Comment: Huh?  So it is least likely that exactly $3$ are forgeries, but *more* likely that exactly $4$ are forgeries or that exactly $2$ are forgeries?  Please explain.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If we assume all are bought from a single seller, there's a lack of any sort of independence.  It's still a fictional scenario, but if you take a weighted average of a trustworthy seller and an untrustworthy seller, it would make sense to me to get this type of distribution.

Comment: The issue isn't independence but monotonicity from a *FIXED* set of paintings (and hence *FIXED* coterie of dealers).  Makes little sense.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Monotonicity in a prior doesn't make much sense unless you are already sure of the type of seller.  If you are unsure of whether the seller is trustworthy or untrustworthy, you could assign probabilities to each, and then the meaningful prior would be a convex combination of a monotone increasing function and a monotone decreasing function.  You can most assuredly yield this type of distribution this way.

Comment: You're correct that you can make enough assumptions to get this unusual concave distribution.  I honestly wonder whether that level of model really underlies a question from an OP with reputation $1$ and has the uncertainties expressed in the comments.  But technically you're right.

Comment: It's a question from a textbook, so I'm guessing the question is more about understanding the concepts, rather than how plausible the actual scenario is.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, the art dealer has more information than just "at least one is a forgery" when she discovers that a particular one is a forgery.  This is the reason your answer doesn't match the correct answer.

---

Let $F_i$ denote the event that $i$ are forgeries and $C$ denote the event that she chooses a forgery.  Then

$$\mathbb{P}(F_5 | C) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(F_5)\mathbb{P}(C|F_5)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}$$

A couple of these are trivial: $\mathbb{P}(F_5) = 0.10$ and $\mathbb{P}(C|F_5) = 1$, but the last one requires a little bit of work:

$$\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(C) &= \sum_{i=0}^5\mathbb{P}(F_i)\mathbb{P}(C|F_i) \\&= \sum_{i=0}^5\mathbb{P}(F_i)\cdot \frac{i}{5} \\&= 0.09\cdot \frac{1}{5}+0.02\cdot\frac{2}{5}+0.01\cdot\frac{3}{5} + 0.02\cdot\frac{4}{5}+0.10 \\&= 0.148\end{align*}$$
(here, we also can note that the probability she chooses a forgery is the expected number of forgeries divided by the number of paintings)

Therefore $$\mathbb{P}(F_5|C) = \frac{0.10}{0.148} \approx 0.675675676$$

Comment: Oh so it's kinda like Probability she chooses a forgery = 0.09 (one forgery) * 1/5 (probability of choosing a forgery given there is only one forgery) + 0.02 (two forgeries) * 2/5 (probability of choosing a forgery given there are only forgeries) and so on

I know this doesn't necessarily add new information  just trying to better understand